# Why do you sometimes have a return value in parens, but sometimes not in a Go function signature?

Tags: go

I noticed that Go function signatures sometimes have a return value in parentheses, and sometimes do not. 
Is this just a matter of taste, or is there a deeper implication to choosing one over the other.

**I've looked through the go documentation, and in go specs in blog articles etc, and not found anything conclusive to answer this question. Most function signature definitions I've come across gloss over this point, and that is why I believe the answer is nuanced.**

```
  func Example(num int) (error){
    ..
  }

  func Example(num int) error {
    ..  
  }
```

Comment: Downvote means "The question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". No further explanation is required by downvoters.  In this case, lack of research effort seems the most likely explanation.

Comment: I have looked, and I've not found anything definitive. Your comment is much more productive than a downvote because it is actionable.

Comment: You've looked where, for what? For the definition of a down-vote perhaps? Hover over the down-vote arrow, and you'll see the text I quoted.

Comment: I can't help you find happiness, but you can help me find answers :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the function has one return value, it means the same thing with or without parentheses. Without parentheses is typically preferred.

If the function has more than one return value then parentheses are required.

```
func Example() (string, error) {
    return "", nil
}
```

If there are named return values, parentheses are also required.

```
func Example() (s string) {
    s = ""
    return
}
```

Comment: Without parenthesis is _always_ preferred, not just typically. This is why gofmt enforces that style.